# Can I force termination a goroutine without waiting for it to return?

Tags: select, concurrency, garbage-collection, go, goroutine

Let me use an example:

```
func WaitForStringOrTimeout() (string, error) {
  my_channel := make(chan string)
  go WaitForString(my_channel)

  select {
  case found_string := <-my_channel:
    return found_string, nil
  case  <-time.After(15 * time.Minute):
    return nil, errors.New("Timed out waiting for string")
  }
}
```

In this simple example, I have some function WaitForString which blocks for awhile and eventually may return a string. I want to wrap WaitForString with this code which either returns the same string or times out with an error.

If a string is found quickly, is there still a goroutine running with a 15 minute sleep statement somewhere or is this garbage collected somehow?

If the timeout occurs and a string is never found, is there still a goroutine running WaitForString, even though there are no other routines that could observe it's output? What if WaitForString allocates a lot of memory but never returns?

Is there some way I can make WaitForString() become aware of the timeout occurring and give up?

Comment: Yes, it will keep running even if the output channel is closed. The timeout detection should live in `WaitForString`, I don't think there's a way to clean up the goroutine by wrapping it.

Comment: Sure, I could modify WaitForString(), but this is a simple example. What if the 2nd case isn't a timeout but is instead WaitForOtherString(). I only need to wait until one of them finishes. Then I'm stuck again as I still need a function "above" both of these two with the select statement. How can I stop the slower goroutine?

Comment: Ultimately you need to manage the interruptions yourself. Have a look at http://play.golang.org/p/bpOGkIN9Ng for instance. WaitForString() needs to be aware that it may be interrupted, and there needs to be a mechanism to interrupt it. Maybe you can use panic/recover as well.

Comment: This is what I was worried about. So, if WaitForString accepted an exit channel, but then called into other functions which could block, I'd need to create another channel for each of those functions, call them inside a select with all of the harnessing you show in your demo, and then tell them to exit early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no there isn't a way to stop another goroutine.  There is a [`runtime.Goexit`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit) function that can be used to cause the current goroutine to exit (even if called from a deep call frame), but nothing to cause other goroutines to exit.

For the specific case of the `time` module, there isn't a separate goroutine handling each timer or ticker: instead, timers are centrally managed by the runtime so it can tell when it next needs to wake up.

While there's no goroutine hanging around, the channel and a small bookkeeping struct will stick around for the 15 minutes.

If this is a problem, consider using `time.NewTimer` instead of `time.After`, and manually stop the timer when you return.  For example:

```
t := time.NewTimer(15 * time.Minute)
defer t.Stop()
select {
case found_string := <-my_channel:
    return found_string, nil
case  <-t.C:
    return nil, errors.New("Timed out waiting for string")
}
```

`time.After` is really useful for exact periodic behaviour, whereas `time.NewTimer` works fine for simple timeouts.

Comment: Related, Does this mean that I the time module is something that I couldn't implement in go? IE: Is it possible for me to write a goroutine that operates the same way as the timer and gets woken up by something external to the code?

Comment: You could probably implement something similar with `syscall.Select`: the point being that if you have two timers set to expire in 1 second and 2 seconds respectively, you don't need two goroutines to wake them: instead you could have one goroutine that waits for 1 second and then wakes the first timer, and then waits another second to wake the second one.  Managing this kind of data structure can be a little more complex, but it is doable.